# How to manually update an ArrayController

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my Application I have the following `rawNodes` property, which I am using as an application-wide cache:

```
var App = Ember.Application.createWithMixins({
    ...
    /**
      The rawNodes property is a nodes deposit to be used
      to populate combo boxes etc.

    **/
    rawNodes: null,

    getNodes: function () {
        if (!this.rawNodes) {
            this.rawNodes = this.Node.find();
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

In some of my controllers I am modifying data which should also be updated in this generic cache. I would like to implement a couple of functions, to update a given node, and to delete a given node. Something like:

```
updateNode: function(node_id, node) {
    this.rawNodes.update(node_id, node);
},

deleteNode: function(node_id) {
    this.rawNodes.delete(node_id);
}
```

But I do not really know how to work with an ArrayController, not even if those operations are at all possible. I see no examples of this kind of procedures in the [ArrayController documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html). Could somebody offer an example, or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a `rawNodes` property, I think it might be more useful to
maintain a `Node` model and a `NodesController`. Assign the `model` property
with `setupController` so you can be sure that nodes are always fetched.

Since this is an application-wide cache, use `needs` in `ApplicationController` so it can delegate to its methods.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    this.controllerFor("nodes").set("model", App.Node.find());
  }
});

App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  needs: "nodes",
});

App.NodesController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  getNodes: function() {
    // ...
  }
});

App.NodeController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  updateNode: function() {
    // ...
  },

  deleteNode: function() {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: That makes sense, but still: how do I implement `updateNode` and `deleteNode`?

Comment: That's a good point. I guess those two methods should go in a `NodeController` (answer updated) for actions on a single resource. In terms of actually updating and deleting, that depends on the model. For example, if you're using `ember-data` then you want to modify the property and then call `node.store.commit()` or `node.deleteRecord()`. If your model is a plain `Ember.Object`, then you'll have to implement the methods yourself using `$.ajax` or whatever you need to use for your app.